# Which compact 3-manifolds with boundary embed in $\mathbb{S}^3.$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

This is a more sensible (IMHO) restatement of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227498/on-compact-orientable-3-manifolds-with-non-empty-boundary):

*Which* Compact $3$-manifolds with boundaries embed in $\mathbb{S}^3?$ Is there any hope of a characterization?

Comment: The embedding problem is algorithmically decidable, http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0815

Comment: As far as I know, no characterisation exists and any would constitute original research.  There is a well-known answer in the case your manifold's boundary is $S^2$.  But as soon as you get to $S^1 \times S^1$ boundary, distinguishing between knot exteriors in $S^3$ vs homology spheres is fussy business.  But it also depends on what you consider a worthwhile answer.  If "the fundamental group is normally generated by a meridian" works for you, then you do have a satisfactory answer, but your comments below suggest you think this is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 11):

There is a theorem of Fox that more or less deals with this.  Any such manifold is a complement of (possibly knotted) handlebodies.

> **Theorem:** Every compact connected 3-submanifold $Y$ of the 3-sphere can be reimbedded in the 3-sphere so that the exterior of the image of $Y$ is a union of handlebodies, i.e. regular neighborhoods of embedded graphs.

R. H. Fox, [*On the imbedding of polyhedra in 3-space*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969291?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Ann. of Math. (2) 49 (1948), 462–470.

Comment: A relevant paper is Kei Nakamura's http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4062

Comment: But I am not sure that really answers the question, since if I give you some hairy manifold with boundary, how do you know if it is the complement of a bunch of handlebodies in $\mathbb{S}^3?$ If it is, there is obviously a decision procedure (keep trying elements of the mapping class group, and checking the result), the other direction seems much harder (but apparently addressed in the Krushkal comment), Still, some human-understandble criterion would be good...

Comment: This is the initial step in Sedgwick et. al.'s algorithm.